# How to disable a parallel run for a specific SpecFlow scenario?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, specflow

Is it possible to exclude a specflow scenario from parallel run?

I set up parallel run for all the assembly by doing this:

```
[assembly: Parallelize(Workers = 10, Scope = ExecutionScope.ClassLevel)]
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs file.

But now I need to exclude one specific scenario from parallel run. How can I do it?

Answer (score -2):

One way to solve this is to use the [NonParallelizable Attribute, provided by NUnit](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NonParallelizable-Attribute).
Example:

```
namespace Tests
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestsSetUpFixture
    {
         //setup the tests
    }   

    [TestFixture]
    [NonParallelizable]
    public class TestFixture1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestFixture1_Test()
        {
            //do stuff in your test
        }
    }
}
```

NUnit provides this documentation:

> This attribute is used to indicate that the test on which it appears
>   may not be run in parallel with any other tests. The attribute takes
>   no arguments and may be used at the assembly, class or method level.
>
> When used at the assembly level, its only effect is that execution
>   begins on the non-parallel queue. Test suites, fixtures and test cases
>   will continue to run on the same thread unless a fixture or method is
>   marked with the Parallelizable Attribute.
>
> When used on a test fixture or method, that test will be queued on the
>   non-parallel queue and will not run while other tests marked as
>   Parallelizable are being run.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MS Test

Comment: The question is asking for a Specflow solution which means the TestFixture is a generated file.